# How to access class variable in decorator function

Tags: python, class, oop, python-decorators

Is it possible to create a decorator function without argument that is able to access class variables. I found similar questions but they always refer to instance variables and not class variables and the variables are generally only accessed when the decorated method is called.

I want to reference the class variable at class definition not after instantiation.

Other solutions such as creating a Meta class come to mind, but I only want to use one class and a decorator without argument.

I am able to implement the required functionality without the use of decorators the following way with the desired results.

```py
class B:
    b=3
    resetFuns=[]

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
        self.y=x+self.b


    def foo(self):
        self.y=self.x+self.b

    resetFuns.append(foo)

    def reset(self):
        for f in self.resetFuns:
            f(self)

test=B(4)
print(test.y)
B.b=9
print(test.y)
test.reset()
print(test.y)

7
7
13
```

But I want to use a decorator similar to this.

```py
class A:
    b=3
    resetFuns=[] ##class variable I want to access

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
        self.y=x+self.b

    def resetDecorator(func):
        resetFuns.append(func) ##can't reference resetFuns like this 
        return func

    @resetDecorator
    def foo(self):
        self.y=self.x+self.b

    def reset(self):
        for f in resetFuns:
            f(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```py
def resetDecoratorCreator(resetFuns):
    def resetDecorator(func):
        resetFuns.append(func)
        return func
    return resetDecorator

class B:
    b=3
    resetFuns=[]
    resetDecorator = resetDecoratorCreator(resetFuns)

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
        self.y=x+self.b

    @resetDecorator
    def foo(self):
        self.y=self.x+self.b

    def reset(self):
        for f in self.resetFuns:
            f(self)
```

will get you what you're looking for.